# Codewars "Closest and Smallest" - mismatch with expected output

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

I have written the following code for a Codewars 5kyu challenge [*Closest and Smallest*](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5868b2de442e3fb2bb000119).

> #### Input
>
> - a string `strng` of n positive numbers (n = 0 or n >= 2) Let us call
>     weight of a number the sum of its digits. For example `99` will have
>     "weight" `18`, `100` will have "weight" `1`.
>
> Two numbers are "close" if the difference of their weights is small.
>
> #### Task:
>
> For each number in `strng` calculate its "weight" and then find
>   two numbers of `strng` that have:
>
> - the smallest difference of weights ie that are the closest
> - with the smallest weights
> - and with the smallest indices (or ranks, numbered
>     from 0) in `strng`
>
> #### Output:
>
> - an array of two arrays, each subarray in the following format:
>
>   ```
>   [number-weight, index in strng of the corresponding number, original
>   corresponding number in strng]
>   ```
>
> The two subarrays are sorted in ascending order by their number
>   weights if these weights are different, by their indexes in the string
>   if they have the same weights.

I'm using Jest in node to test it locally - and it is all working fine.
But it's not passing the tests on Codewars. I would really appreciate any tips on this. Thanks!

```
function closest(string) {
  if (string.length < 1)
    return [];
  const nums = string.split(" ");
  const weights = nums.map(e => e.split('').reduce((p, a) => Number(p) + Number(a)));
  const indexedWeights = [];
  let indexCounter = 0;
  for (let w of weights)
    indexedWeights.push([w, indexCounter++, Number(nums.shift())])
  let collected = [];
  indexedWeights.forEach(iw => {
    const iWCopy = indexedWeights.filter(item => item !== iw);
    const closest = iWCopy.reduce((a, b) => Math.abs(b[0] - iw[0]) < Math.abs(a[0] - iw[0]) ? b : a);
    const diff = Math.abs(closest[0] - iw[0]);
    collected.push([diff, iw[0], iw[1], iw[2]]);
  });
  collected.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
  const lowestDiff = collected[0][0]
  const result = collected.filter(n => n[0] === lowestDiff)
  result.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
  return [result[0].splice(1, 4), result[1].splice(1, 4)];
}
```

Test:

```
const closest = require("../5kyu_challenges/closestAndSmallest");
describe("closest", () => {
  test("returns an array containing 2 sub-arrays which consist of 3 numbers representing closest and smallest numbers", () => {
    expect(closest("")).toEqual([]);
    expect(closest("456899 50 11992 176 272293 163 389128 96 290193 85 52")).toEqual([ [13, 9, 85], [14, 3, 176] ]);
  });
  test("sorts by index number if weights are equal", () => {
    expect(closest("239382 162 254765 182 485944 134 468751 62 49780 108 54")).toEqual([ [8, 5, 134], [8, 7, 62] ]);
    expect(closest("403749 18 278325 97 304194 119 58359 165 144403 128 38")).toEqual([ [11, 5, 119], [11, 9, 128] ]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you add the result of the codewars test results, so we can see what is failing?

Comment: It's passing some, but failing some too: 
Time: 1082ms Passed: 82 Failed: 139 Exit Code: 1
Example of failing test:
`Expected: '[[10, 1, 154], [10, 9, 37]]', instead got: '[[10, 9, 37], [10, 1, 154]]'`

Comment: Does it fail the same tests that you have locally? Or are they different tests?

Comment: I imagine it's an issue with your code, as Codewars has two sets of tests, an example one which usually is really simple and then a load of more in depth tests, where katas usually fail. I would suggest you add more tests cases... and if it still fails, maybe comment on the kata, sometimes the tests are wrong...

Comment: In the result you passed, the values are reversed, that is why it does not pass the tests

Comment: thanks Keff - good spot!

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is to sort the output also by the indexes of the matches (I highlight):

> The two subarrays are sorted in ascending order by their number weights if these weights are different, **by their indexes** in the string if they have the same weights.

So change this line in your code:

```
result.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
```

with this:

```
result.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1] || a[2] - b[2])
```

#### Efficiency

Be aware that sorting has a time complexity of *O(nlogn)*. So if the input is a very large array, sorting `collected` may be an inferior solution compared to scanning the `collected` array for minimum values.